# Spring Library for extracting mail replies without reply history

Tags: spring-boot

I have an issue with extracting just the mail reply message/content using my custom parser. Whenever user replies directly from email (Gmail/Thunderbird/Outlook/etc) the previous replies are included in nested format but depending on the client used, the format of the reply messages differs, specially for outlook.

What I want to do is only extract the actual reply of user without the nested previous replies.

I also observed that there are times when these formats changes, so I need to update my parser to work with the new format.

I am thinking that there are available and tested spring library for parsing the email content and able to remove the nested previous replies so that I can just get the exact reply from the user.

I am using springboot for my project by the way.

TIA